# How can i get the indices after i use the sparse function?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mask, sparse-matrix

I created a mask, and then i used the sparse function. Here is part of the code:

```
 BW = createMask(handle);
 sparse_image=sparse(BW);
```

Now, inside of sparse_image i have all the indices where the logical value were one. I would like to take this indices and separate them so that in vector XX i will have all the x values and in vector YY i will have all the y values respectively. Just to clarify what i want, values XX(1),YY(1) are an index in my sparse_image matrix.

Comment: It works! I  didn't know how to do it,and didn't know the find function.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use the regular `find` function for this so

```
[R, C] = find(sparse_image)
```

As Shai points out, there is a good chance that `C` from above is your `XX` and `R` from above is your `YY` because rows of a matrix very often correspond to the y-axis of an image.

Comment: shouldn't it be `[yy xx] = find(...)`? converting from row-column matrix indices to x-y coordinate system?